# Show divergence of infinite sum outside of $(-1,1)\backslash\{0\}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, sums-of-squares

I have to show that this dreadfull thing is infinite $\forall a\in(-1,1)\backslash\{0\}$
$$f(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1-(\pm a/2)^{n+1}}{(2\mp a) a^{n+1}}\right)^2$$

I can show that if $0<a_1>a_2<1$ then $f(a_2)<f(a_1)$ and conversely for $-1<a_2<a_1<0$ but I don't know how to get further than that :(

Comment: Can you tell us how the $\pm$ is determined?

Comment: It's a series with all positive summands and the limit of the summands as $n\to\infty$ is nonzero (indeed, it is $+\infty$). That is enough to say the series is 'infinite'.